# How to calculate pixels into percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, percentage

```
var helperPos_x = $('.helper').offset().left;

$('.box').css('left', helperPos_x + helper_width + 'px');
```

I got this code above but it sets the value in pixels so `.helper` width should also be in pixels to accomplish this. How can I turn `helperPos_x` value into percentage? Is it possible at all? Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this.

```
helperPos_x = ($('.helper').offset().left / $(window).width() * 100);
```